# Two arrays with objects to become new array with same lenght, but all data from original arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js, object

I have two arrays with an equal amount of objects in them. I want to take each array's first object and put them together in a new array as the first object in the array. I then would like to keep doing that with the following objects.

```
var a = [{akey: 'something'}, {bkey: 'somethingelse'}];
var b = [{ckey: 'somethinghere'}, {dkey: 'somethingdiffrent'}];

//some-code-here to make the below part.

var newArray  = [{akey: 'something', ckey: 'somethinghere'},
                 {bkey: 'somethingelse', dkey: 'somethingdiffrent'}];
```

So that I still have the data from the objects in the old arrays but put together as two new objects in one new array. 
Except duplicate keys, then they can be overwritten, like so:

```
{aKey: 'data'} + {aKey: 'data'} whould just be {aKey: 'data'}
```

Hope this makes some sense, the arrays will be the same length, a.length = b.length, but the objects might be different in sense. The final array will be put out on an ng-repeat, (angular project).

Comment: `length !== lenght`, the first is right.

Comment: are your keys always going to start with a letter of the alphabet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to combine the objects and use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for mapping the array.

```js
var a = [{akey: 'something'}, {bkey: 'somethingelse'}, { foo: 'from a' }],
    b = [{ckey: 'somethinghere'}, {dkey: 'somethingdiffrent'}, { foo: 'from b' }],
    c = a.map(function (el, i) {
        return Object.assign({}, el, b[i]);
    });

console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you like to get `{ foo: 'from a' }`, you can switch `el` and `b[i]`.

```
return Object.assign({}, b[i], el);
```

```js
var a = [{akey: 'something'}, {bkey: 'somethingelse'}, { foo: 'from a' }],
    b = [{ckey: 'somethinghere'}, {dkey: 'somethingdiffrent'}, { foo: 'from b' }],
    c = a.map(function (el, i) {
        return Object.assign({}, b[i], el);
    });

console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This solved my problem!

Comment: Yes im sorry, i unfortunately missclicked on the wrong button and now i cant seem to find where to redo it. I voted on yours but since i have less then 15 points i cant get it to show yet, and thats why i commented on your answer instead to at least let you know im greatful.